# How to create updateable/inseartable view on QGIS with a sequence id?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql

I have a huge point dataset that takes a long time to insert new stuff when using QGIS

This table has an id column of type serial

To go around this problem I've created an empty view that has the same exact fields as its original table. at first tried limit 0 but it didn't let it update so I limited the table with a where condition that never gets fulfilled, so i end up with an empty table

Problem now is that when inserting new features, they don't get the id of the original table, and new inserts on the original table need the id to activate other triggers

How to make it use the same sequence as the original table and enable people to insert new features on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to remove the id from the view, this way QGIS didn't try forcing a null value on to the original table and the original table was able to generate the new id